# Are there any smart plugs using home powerlines or ethernet instead of WiFi?

Tags: smart-plugs

I'm using power lines at home and trying to avoid using WiFi as much as possible. And many powerline adapters to ethernet include a plug. Moreover, many suppliers of powerlines also offer smart switches in their catalog. However, I don't find any combination of smart plug using powerlines instead of WiFi. Can you help me with that?

I already explored websites of TP-Link, Sonoff, and others. But I hope I'm missing the one that offers that.

Comment: IIRC the older X10 protocol communicated over the power wires. Not sure it’s still a thing (pretty lousy experience with that back in the day). KNX supports multiple media including powerline but I believe devices are on the pricier side. Never used it myself.

Comment: I'm using HomePlug AV protocol https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HomePlug#HomePlug_AV. The connection is faster than WiFi, at least in my home.

Answer (score 0):

I only know of (and have used) X10 before.  Eventually I threw them out and replaced them with Z-Wave devices.

They work on powerlines.  The issues I had were

- It didn't work across 3-phase system (when I realised this, I bought a 3-phase coupler)
- Maximum distance was 30m (back then).  This was not communicated to me and was a deal breaker for me.
- The system was too visible for my wife's liking.  (Z-Wave or Zigbee devices can be hidden).

Otherwise it worked fine.

Here is a [plug on the X10 site](https://www.x10.com/products/sr227?_pos=4&_sid=65cdf144b&_ss=r)

[image]